# How does Snowflake do instantaneous resizes?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I was using Snowflake and I was surprised how it is able to do instantaneous resizes. Here is a very [10s video](https://gyazo.com/4af7d9f1c9415521efd300e7261aa80d) of how it instantly does a resize, and the query is still 'warm' the next time it is run (Note I have a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the query so it never returns from cache):

[image]

How is Snowflake able to do instantaneous resizes (completely different than something like Redshift)? Does this mean that it just has a fleet of servers that are always on, and a resize is just a virtual allocation of memory/cpu to run that task? Is the underlying data stored on a shared disk or in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question about resizing in short: Yes, you are absolutely right.

As far as I know Snowflake manages a pool of running servers in the background. All customers can be assigned something from here.
Consequence: A resize for you from S to XS is a reallocation of a server from that pool.

Most probably the Virtual Private Snowflake-Edition behaves differently as those accounts don't share resources (e.g. Virtual Warehouses) with other accounts (outside that VPS). More infos: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-editions.html#virtual-private-snowflake-vps

Regarding your storage-question:
Snowflake's storage layer is basically a storage service, e.g. Amazon S3. In here Snowflake saves the data in columnar format, to be more presice in micro-partitions. More information regarding micro-partitions can be found here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html

Your virtual warehouse accesses this storage layer (remote disk) or - if the query was run before - a cache. There are a local disc cache (this is your virtual warehouse using SSD-storage) and a result cache (available across virtual warehouses for queries within the last 24 hours): https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Caching-in-Snowflake-Data-Warehouse

Comment: thanks for this answer and all the links -- very helpful. One question if you have an idea: you mention a `storage layer like S3` -- this makes sense, but how does it get such fast access to it? For example, to return a non-cached query in under 50ms, where it has to access/seek to the appropriate files and send the data back over the network? S3 has always seemed like a 'slow(ish)-storage-layer' to me.

Comment: Snowflake has a lot of metadata stored in the services layer (e.g. distinct values, min, max, ...). All the metadata is used to prune the micro partitions that have to be selected very efficiently. 

And: If you query e.g. count(*) it is querying nothing from AWS but just the own metadata.

Comment: thanks, could you please elaborate on what you mean by "service layer" ? Does that mean (more-or-less) in memory on the node that is doing the query?

Comment: Can you have a look Here? 

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html

Otherwise I can answer more questions tomorrow in Chat :)

Comment: I highly recommend signing up for Snowflake University and going through the "First Concepts" series that explains all the layers in the Snowflake stack https://snowflakeuniversity.mindtickle.com/

Answer (score 0):

To extend the existing answer, `ALTER WAREHOUSE` in standard setup is non-blocking statement, which means it returns control as soon as it is submitted.

> [ALTER WAREHOUSE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-warehouse.html)
>
> ```
> WAIT_FOR_COMPLETION = FALSE | TRUE
> ```
>
> **When resizing a warehouse, you can use this parameter to block the return of the ALTER WAREHOUSE command until the resize has finished provisioning all its servers.** Blocking the return of the command when resizing to a larger warehouse serves to notify you that your servers have been fully provisioned and the warehouse is now ready to execute queries using all the new resources.
>
> Valid values
>
> - FALSE: The ALTER WAREHOUSE command returns immediately, before the warehouse resize completes.
> - **TRUE: The ALTER WAREHOUSE command will block until the warehouse resize completes.**
>
> Default:    FALSE

For instance:

```
ALTER WAREHOUSE <warehouse_name> SET WAREHOUSE_SIZE = XLARGE WAIT_FOR_COMPLETION = TRUE;
```

---

**EDIT:**

[The Snowflake Elastic Data Warehouse](http://info.snowflake.net/rs/252-RFO-227/images/Snowflake_SIGMOD.pdf)

> 3.2.1  Elasticity and Isolation VWs are **pure compute resources.**
>
> They can be created,destroyed, or resized at any point, on demand.  Creating or destroying a VW has no effect on the state of the database. It is perfectly legal (and encouraged) that users shut down all their  VWs  when  they  have  no  queries.   This  elasticity allows users to dynamically match their compute resources to usage demands, independent of the data volume.

Comment: sure, but what about from "off" to "on"? With the resizing when it's always on it can do it 'instantaneously' in the background and just update the forwarding address as necessary, but what about when it's off?

Comment: @David542 I am not aware if it is described anywhere. We do not even know how many cores/RAM each worker node have. I assume they have some pool preallocated and scale on demand, but such technical details are available for SF engineers.

Comment: @David542 Actually there is a whitepaper giving general overview: http://info.snowflake.net/rs/252-RFO-227/images/Snowflake_SIGMOD.pdf